# Visual interpretation of the Laplace-transform

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, visualization

I was wondering if there is a visual interpretation for the Laplace-transform.

For example, you can visualize integrals by sketching the area under the graph. That way it has a visual meaning. I’m curious if there is something similar with the Laplace transform.

Comment: This question is somewhere between not research-level, though I'll imagine an analyst could give a really interesting answer, and too broad—what sort of answer do you have in mind?  Would thinking in the [complex-frequency domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain) count as a visual interpretation?  It does not seem to me that this question is appropriate for MO in its current form.

Comment: if you google the title of the question you will get many hits, are those along the lines of what you are looking for?